# How can I create a wizard-like experience with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I want to break a big web page up into bite-size chunks for the user, so that they are not overwhelmed by the size of the page / the amount of information they have to enter (all at once, anyway).

I'm using Meteor, and would like to know how to accomplish this with that platform.

The first idea that comes to mind is to create a separate template for each "sub page" I want to show the user, and then present the templates one after another. I'm thinking maybe something like this:

```
<body>
<h2>Thirteen Ways of Looking at a Duckbilled Platypus</h2>

<br/>
<br/>

<div class="container">
   {{> whizzardBlizzard}}
</div>

</body>

<template name="whizzardBlizzard">
    <form>
    {{#if firstStep}}
    {{> firstStepTemplate}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if secondStep}}
    {{> secondStepTemplate}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if thirdStep}}
    {{> thirdStepTemplate}}
    {{/if}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
    </form>
</template>

<template name="firstStepTemplate">
  <h2>Step 1</h2>
</template>

<template name="secondStepTemplate">
  <h2>Step 2</h2>
</template>

<template name="thirdStepTemplate">
  <h2>Step 3</h2>
</template>
```

The submit event handler would be a template event method that would save the data entered at each step and update the value of a "counter", something like:

```
Template.whizzardBlizzard.events({
    "submit form": function (event) {
        //event.preventDefault(); <= should this be uncommented?
        // save the vals to a new document in a collection
        Session.set('stepNum', Session.get('stepNum') + 1);
    }
});
```

The "firstStep," "secondStep," etc. would perhaps be template helpers, such as:

```
Template.whizzardBlizard.helpers({
    firstStep: function() {
        return (Session.get('stepNum') == 1);
    },
    secondStep: function() {
        return (Session.get('stepNum') == 2)
    },
    thirdStep: function() {
        return (Session.get('stepNum') == 3)
    }
    . . . // etc.
});
```

...but am not sure if this will really fill the bill or be the best approach. Is there a "blessed" way of doing this with Meteor, or an accepted pattern?

Comment: You might be interested in [intro.js](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/), which has been adapted to [a meteor package](https://atmospherejs.com/rexzh0u/introjs).